# Unable to Install Webmatrix

Tags: webmatrix, web-platform-installer

*Error Occurs*

**Microsoft Web Platform Installer couldn't find the product you tried to install. Either the link you clicked is incorrect or you may be overriding you feed with a different feed**

[image: Unable to install]

The link for Microsoft webmatrix does not work. When the web installer tries to download and error occurs:

Microsoft Web Platform Installer couldn't find the product you tried to install. Either the link you clicked is incorrect or you may be overriding you feed with a different feed.

I get this error when I try to install the Microsoft webmatrix [www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/‎] on my Window 7 OS.
Can anyone help!

Comment: Silly question - do you have Windows 7 *SP1* installed?  If you're running Win7 without SP1, we have a few known issues.

Comment: I have Windows 7 SP1 installed justin beckwith

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your log file from %localappdata%\microsoft\web platform installer\logs\webpi - try to find the log file that matches up date/time with when you clicked the link and got the error message - thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Attempted to install PHP 5.2.17 on an IIS7 / 2008 standard 64bit on a VM running on Azure from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx

The download link gave me the executable PHP52.exe.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=PHP52

Clicking on the exe the Web Platform Installer opened and I received the message:

> Microsoft Web Platform Installer couldn't find the product you tried to install
>   as displayed in your screenshot above.

So selected:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=PHP53

This downloads the exe PHP53.exe  (i.e php 5.3.5).

When running this exe the message is no loner displayed and my installation can continue.

Hope that helps someone

Scott